How to stop TextView: UIViewRepresentable text from being covered by the keyboard
I have a TextView: UIViewRepresentable struct that creates a UITextView that I use within a SwiftUI view. My problem is that if the text is low enough on the screen, when I tap it to edit the text, the keyboard pops up and covers the text. All the solutions I've found online are either really old or aren't specific to the way I have things laid out. I've also seen people recommend IQKeyboardManager, but I'd rather stay away from using third party libraries.
Here is the source code for TextView and SwiftUI view. I've tried in the past adding constraints with KeyboardLayoutGuide, but have found no success with any configuration of it. I know I can use notifications to track when the user brings up the keyboard, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution. If there is none, then I'll have to go with the notification approach, which I've also tried implementing to no success.
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct NoteRowItem: View {
    private var id: String
    @EnvironmentObject var mobilePublisher: MobilePublisher
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var spaceState: SpaceState
    @ObservedObject var note: Note
    @Binding var newNoteIndex: Int?
    @Binding private var targetedId: String
    
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State private var noteText: String
    @State private var textHeight: CGFloat = 20
    
    init(note: Note, newNoteIndex: Binding<Int?>, targetedId: Binding<String>) {
        self.note = note
        self.noteText = note.text
        self._newNoteIndex = newNoteIndex
        self._targetedId = targetedId
        self.id = note.id
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextView(text: $noteText, textHeight: $textHeight)
            .frame(height: textHeight)
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
            .font(.system(size: 16, design: .default))
            .padding(.vertical, 20)
            .background(targetedId == id ? Color("Accent") : Color("Main")) // Change color if hovered with drag/drop
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .disabled(targetedId == id) // Disable TextField when not focused so drag/drop works
            .focused($isFocused)
            .onChange(of: isFocused) { newFocus in
                if !newFocus {
                    saveNote()
                }
            }
            .contentShape(.dragPreview, RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Constants.UI.rowItemRadius))
            .overlay(
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: nil, height: 0.75)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color("Accent")), alignment: .bottom) // Bottom black border
            .overlay(
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: nil, height: 0.75)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color("Accent")), alignment: .top) // Top black border
            .onTapGesture {
                isFocused = true
            }
            .onAppear {
                // Focus newly-created note
                if self.note.orderIndex == self.newNoteIndex ?? -1 {
                    isFocused = true
                    self.newNoteIndex = nil
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.textHeight = calculateTextHeight(for: self.noteText) // Adjust width as per your layout
                }
            }
    }
    
    // Calculate text height for initial load
    private func calculateTextHeight(for text: String) -> CGFloat {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = text
        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        return size.height
    }
    
    // MARK: - CoreData
    
    // Edit or delete note in CoreData
    private func saveNote() {
        // If text is empty, delete the note
        if noteText == "" {
            do {
                try note.delete(context: viewContext)
            } catch let error as AppError {
                spaceState.error = error
            } catch {
                spaceState.error = AppError.noteError(
                    title: "Error!",
                    subtitle: "Unexpected error while deleting note: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } else {
            note.editNote(text: noteText, context: viewContext)
        }
    }
}

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var textHeight: CGFloat
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isEditable = true
        textView.textColor = UIColor.black
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        textView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
        textView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        if uiView.text != text {
            uiView.text = text
        }
        
        uiView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.textHeight = uiView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: uiView.frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent: TextView
        
        init(_ parent: TextView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.parent.text = textView.text
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parent.textHeight = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height
            }
        }
    }
}

Edit: Another side issue that I have is if the text in TextView is long enough, sometimes it appears cut off, until I tap on it and edit it, in which case the rest of the text appears.
